# How to get the email address from the record Owner in a map?

Tags: apex, map, tasks

Requirement: When a task is created for a Lead or Contact check if the Description contains the email address of the Lead/Contact Owner. This is a method I am calling from a trigger.

> //  ListEmail = ReturnContactEmail.ContactEmail(currLead.OwnerId);
>   This line breaks too many SOQL queries

```
public static void AnalyzeTask(List < Id > LeadId, List < Id > ContId, List < Id > TaskId) {
      Set < Lead > LList = new Set < Lead > ();
      Set < Contact > LContact = new Set < Contact > ();
      Map < Id, Lead > LeadMap = new Map < Id, Lead > ([SELECT Id, Email_Opt_In__c, Email,OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id In: LeadId]);
      Map < Id, Contact > ContMap = new Map < Id, Contact > ([SELECT Id, Email_Opt_In__c, LeadSource, Email,OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id In: ContId]);
      Map < Id, Task > TaskMap = new Map < Id, Task > ([SELECT Id, Whoid, Type, Subject, Description from Task WHERE Id In: TaskId]);
      List<String> ListEmail= new List<String>();

      System.Debug('Task Id Size' + TaskId.size());

      For(Task t: TaskMap.values()) {
          if (t.whoId != Null) {
              string whoid = t.whoId;
              boolean IsLead = whoid.startsWith('00Q');
              boolean IsContact = whoid.startsWith('003');
              // Is my task an Email ?
              if (t.Type == 'Email') {
                  string subject = t.Subject;
                  if (subject.startsWith('Email:'))
                      if (IsLead) { System.debug('Lead map size:' + Leadmap.size());
                          for (Lead currLead: Leadmap.values()) {
                              string description = t.Description;
                              List < string > Ldesc = new List < string > ();
                              Ldesc = description.split('\r\n', 2);
                              System.debug('Description:' + Ldesc[0]);
                              System.debug('Leads Email:' + currLead.Email);
                            //  ListEmail = ReturnContactEmail.ContactEmail(currLead.OwnerId); This line breaks too many SOQL queries
                              if (Ldesc[0].contains(ListEmail[0]) && Ldesc[0].startsWith('Additional To:')) {
                                  currLead.Email_Opt_In__c = True;
                                  LList.add(currLead);
                              }
                          }
                      } else if (IsContact) {

                      for (Contact currContact: ContMap.values()) {
                          string description = t.Description;
                          List < string > Ldesc = new List < string > ();
                          Ldesc = description.split('\r\n', 2);
                       // ListEmail = ReturnContactEmail.ContactEmail(currContact.OwnerId); This line breaks too many SOQL queries
                          if (Ldesc[0].contains(ListEmail[0]) && Ldesc[0].startsWith('Additional To:')) {
                              currContact.Email_Opt_In__c = True;
                              LContact.add(currContact);
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
    }
    List<Lead> listLead = new List<Lead>(LList);
    Update listLead;
    List<Contact> listContact = new List<Contact>(LContact);
    Update listContact;
  }
```

Comment: And you question is?????

Comment: The question is below. How do I get the current lead's owner's email address and check if it is contained in the Description without running into a "too many SOQL queries"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an update to the code you provided, this may help with further debugging.

Note the following changes:

1. Updating your task SOQL to be more selective eliminating many of your if statements
2. Removing redundant lists
3. Removing redundant variables and assignments
4. Adding a try catch and savepoint so if something fails everything rolls back to an appropriate state
5. Utilization of the lead and contact maps to reduce the number loops

---

```
public static void AnalyzeTask(List <Id> LeadId, List <Id> ContId, List <Id> TaskId) 
{
    Set<Lead> leadSet = new Set<Lead>();
    Set<Contact> contactSet = new Set<Contact>();
    Map<Id, Lead> leadsMap = new Map<Id, Lead>([SELECT Id, Email_Opt_In__c, Email, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id In: LeadId]);
    Map<Id, Contact> contactsMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, Email_Opt_In__c, LeadSource, Email, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id In: ContId]);
    List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id, Whoid, Type, Subject, Description FROM Task WHERE Id In: TaskId AND WhoId != NULL AND (Who.Type = 'Lead' OR Who.Type = 'Contact') AND Type = 'Email' AND Subject LIKE 'Email:%'];

    for(Task t: tasks) 
    {
        string whoid = t.whoId;
        boolean IsLead = whoid.startsWith('00Q');
        boolean IsContact = whoid.startsWith('003');
        string subject = t.Subject;
        if (IsLead && t.Description.containsIgnoreCase(currLead.Email)) && t.Description.startsWith('Additional To:'))
        {
            Lead currLead = leadsMap.get(t.OwnerId);
            currLead.Email_Opt_In__c = TRUE;
            leadSet.add(currLead);
        } 
        else if(IsContact && t.Description.containsIgnoreCase(currContact.Email)) && t.Description.startsWith('Additional To:')) 
        {
            Contact currContact = contactMap.get(t.OwnerId);
            currContact.Email_Opt_In__c = TRUE;
            contactSet.add(currContact);
        }
    }

    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    try
    {
        update leadSet;
        update contactSet;
    }
    catch(Exeception ex)
    {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is in this line: 
if (IsLead && t.Description.containsIgnoreCase(currLead.Email)) && t.Description.startsWith('Additional To:'))
I'm asking if the Description contains the email address of the current lead. I would like to know, how to check if the description has the Lead's owner's email address. Example: Lead: Name1 LastName Test,  LeadOwner= Myself.
I need to check if Myself's email address is in the Description of that task.
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Oh, you need to add in Owner.Email into the Lead query and then do t.Description.containsIgnoreCase(currLead.Owner.Email)

Comment: Dude...it worked! I owe you a 12 pack! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is extremely deeply nested, which makes it hard to read. I've added an updated version that while it does not address the main question, should make it easier to answer.

Try this:

```
    public static void AnalyzeTask(List < Id > LeadId, List < Id > ContId, List < Id > TaskId) {
    Set < Lead > LList = new Set < Lead > ();
    Set < Contact > LContact = new Set < Contact > ();
    Map < Id, Lead > LeadMap = new Map < Id, Lead > ([SELECT Id, Email_Opt_In__c, Email, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id In: LeadId]);
    Map < Id, Contact > ContMap = new Map < Id, Contact > ([SELECT Id, Email_Opt_In__c, LeadSource, Email, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id In: ContId]);
    Map < Id, Task > TaskMap = new Map < Id, Task > ([  SELECT Id, Whoid, Type, Subject, Description 
                                                        FROM Task 
                                                        WHERE (Id In :TaskId
                                                            AND Type = 'Email'
                                                            AND Subject LIKE 'Email:%']));
    List < String > ListEmail = new List < String > ();

    for (Task t: TaskMap.values()) {
        if (t.whoId == null) {
            continue;
        }
        string whoid = t.whoId;
        boolean IsLead = whoid.startsWith('00Q');
        boolean IsContact = whoid.startsWith('003');
        string subject = t.Subject;
        if (IsLead) {
            for (Lead currLead: Leadmap.values()) {
                string description = t.Description;
                List < string > Ldesc = new List < string > ();
                Ldesc = description.split('\r\n', 2);
                if (Ldesc[0].contains(ListEmail[0]) && Ldesc[0].startsWith('Additional To:')) {
                    currLead.Email_Opt_In__c = True;
                    LList.add(currLead);
                }
            }
        } else if (IsContact) {
            for (Contact currContact: ContMap.values()) {
                string description = t.Description;
                List < string > Ldesc = new List < string > ();
                Ldesc = description.split('\r\n', 2);
                if (Ldesc[0].contains(ListEmail[0]) && Ldesc[0].startsWith('Additional To:')) {
                    currContact.Email_Opt_In__c = True;
                    LContact.add(currContact);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    List < Lead > listLead = new List < Lead > (LList);
    Update listLead;
    List < Contact > listContact = new List < Contact > (LContact);
    Update listContact;
}
```